# Clearing Chrome's DNS cache from the terminal

Tags: google-chrome, bash, dns

I have written a script to add websites to the hostfile at certain times of the day. For example, it can block Youtube from 8pm - 10pm. It works well, however the changes aren't reflected in Chrome. This has something to do with internal DNS caching in Chrome and seemingly cannot be flushed without going into Chrome's settings or restarting the browser.

Is there any way to flush this cache from the terminal?

Comment: I have removed everything in `/.cache/google-chrome/`... still to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cutting out the network and then restarting it works (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322046/prevent-chrome-from-caching-a-sites-dns-records/4365384#4365384)); on Ubuntu I'm using nmcli. I wrote this as a script called "social-media-break" and run it with an argument for sleep like "5m" or "15m". It relies on the existence of these hosts.socialmediaallow and hosts.normal files, where the "normal" one sends various social media sites to 127.0.0.1.

This is quick and dirty, requires root.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -v
sudo cp /etc/hosts.socialmediaallow /etc/hosts
sleep $1
sudo cp /etc/hosts.normal /etc/hosts
nmcli networking off && nmcli networking on
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing back then.

Comment: Revised to do network restart instead of restarting Chrome, which seems less invasive.

Answer (score -1):

Have you ever tried:

Open a new tab>Type the url in the search box: **chrome://net-internals/#dns**
Hit the “Clear host cache” button.

You may need to flush out socket pools too:
Open a new tab and type the following in search box:
**chrome://net-internals/#sockets**
Click on the “Flush socket pools“:

Comment: I need to be able to do it programatically... I'm sure that would work though.